# spark graphx: how to travers a graph to create a graph of second degree neighbors

Tags: apache-spark

I'm a total beginner with spark / hadoop / graph computation so please
excuse my beginner question.

I've created a graph, using graphx. Now, for every vertex, I want to get
all its second degree neighbors.
so if my graph is:

```
v1 --> v2
v1 --> v4
v1 --> v6
```

I want to get something like:

```
v2 --> v4
v2 --> v6
v4 --> v2
v4 --> v6
v6 --> v2
v6 --> v4
```

My graph is very large, so I would like to do it elegantly and efficiently as possible.

I have a feeling this should not too hard, but as a total newbee to this huge framework, I find myself all over the docs / source trying to figure this one out.

Does anyone have advice on what will be the best way to do that over a
graph instance?

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend cross posting this on the [spark user list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com) much more likely to get an answer

Comment: @aaronman: thanks. I actually started by posting it there: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/graph-reduceByKey-td11447.html

Comment: That's unfortunate seems like it was skipped over, this seems like something you could do with Pregel but I don't know enough about it to answer

Answer (score 11):

From your example, I take your problem to be that you want to construct a graph that has an edge a -> b if an only if in the original graph there was a vertex v and edges v -> a and v -> b. (Which may or may not be a standard definition of "second degree neighbor" in a directed graph, but interesting anyway.)

Here's a solution in Scala. It produces a graph with all the original vertices but only the required edges. I'm putting empty strings as data on all the vertices and edges.

Assuming a SparkContext sc as you'd normally get in the Spark shell, and GraphX available, set up the example graph:

```
val vertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] =
    sc.parallelize(Array((1L,""), (2L,""), (4L,""), (6L,"")))

val edges: RDD[Edge[String]] =
    sc.parallelize(Array(Edge(1L, 2L, ""), Edge(1L, 4L, ""), Edge(1L, 6L, "")))

val inputGraph = Graph(vertices, edges)
```

Crate an alternate set of vertices each annotated with the set of their successors, so, in your example, v1 would be annotated with {v2, v4, v6}.

```
val verticesWithSuccessors: VertexRDD[Array[VertexId]] = 
    inputGraph.ops.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Out)
```

Create a new graph using these vertices and the original edges.

```
val successorSetGraph = Graph(verticesWithSuccessors, edges)
```

Now we need to push these sets along each edge, creating yet another set of vertices, this time all annotated with their neighbors. We need to combine the sets at the destinations vertex, so using Scala `Set` removes duplicates. We also need to remove each vertex from the set of its neighbors, hence the extra `map` tacked on the end.

```
val ngVertices: VertexRDD[Set[VertexId]] =  
    successorSetGraph.mapReduceTriplets[Set[VertexId]] (
        triplet => {
            Iterator((triplet.dstId, triplet.srcAttr.toSet))
        },
        (s1, s2) => s1 ++ s2
    ).mapValues[Set[VertexId]](
        (id: VertexId, neighbors: Set[VertexId]) => neighbors - id
    )
```

Now we're almost ready to create the final graph, but we need an edge for each neighbor relationship:

```
val ngEdges = ngVertices.flatMap[Edge[String]](
  {
    case (source: VertexId, allDests: Set[VertexId]) => {
      allDests.map((dest: VertexId) => Edge(source, dest, ""))
    }
  }
)
```

Now we can put it all together:

```
val neighborGraph = Graph(vertices, ngEdges)
```

I'm sure an expert can do better, especially in terms of performance, but most of the ideas this relies on can be found in the [GraphX Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html).

Comment: I've implemented a similar algorithm using Pregel, but one can run into memory issues when the allDests set grows very large.  The problem seems to be the fact that graphx adopts a vertex cut partitioning strategy, replicating these large vertices across partitions.  It would be interesting to see if anyone has strategies, other than increasing the number of partitions, to tackle similar use-cases where vertex data can grow extremely large.

Comment: Very interesting solution. Can this solution be extended to estimate the n-degree neighbors? Is it enough to apply this solution n times to get n-degree neighbors?